# Seaborn Lattice Plot/ Relationship Plot with Double Y Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I know how to make a lattice plot (https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html) or relationship plot (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot).

However, what if each inidivdual plot needs to be a plot with 2 Y-axis? And within each plot, there are 4 lines, 3 lines using the left Y-axis and 1 line using the right Y-axis, something like the figure below:

[image]

So instead of the 4 scatter plots such as the figure below from the seaborn documentation, I need 4 of my double Y-axis figures... ... I am think of using the FacetGrid function, but it seems like my argument must be an sns plot that can be written in one line only, and I cannot use the matplotlib twinx() function.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Using seaborn may make this harder than it needs to be. I'd create a 4x4 subplot grid in matplotlib and add a twinx axes for each subplot. You can easily loop over the data with `DataFrame.groupby`.